# Determine class instance member type based on static member type in subclass

Tags: typescript

I have a base class called `Parent`:

```js
class Parent {
    static elType = window.Element
    el: InstanceType<typeof Parent['elType']>

    constructor(input: Element) {
        let ctor = this.constructor as typeof Parent
        if (input instanceof ctor.elType) {
            this.el = input
        } else {
            throw new Error()
        }
    }
}
```

It allows instances to be created only if `input` is an instance of `elType` specified in the constructor. If the check passes, an instance member `el` is set to `input`.

Then, I want to create a subclass that allows only `HTMLElement` (which extends `Element`) inputs:

```js
class Child extends Parent {
    static elType = window.HTMLElement
}
```

However, the instance member `el` is not correctly set to `HTMLElement`. It's still `Element`:

```js
let foo = null as unknown as HTMLElement
let ch = new Child(foo)

// Property 'offsetLeft' does not exist on type 'Element'.
ch.el.offsetLeft
```

I think the problem lies in this:

```js
el: InstanceType<typeof Parent['elType']>
```

I'm setting the type of `el` to the `elType` type of `Parent`, which is `Element` and is not affected by `Child`'s static `elType`. My question is - how can I make that work? I need some trick like:

```js
el: InstanceType<typeof {{ current class }}['elType']>
```

Check this in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDQOgjTDQEthokQAVATwAcloBeaAdzJQBMB7dgHQBREEgC2qNHkJUQALmgBJFMTApgSekwA8aRkl4AzOIkkBtAOTUtSCwF0AfHmmFgvFWgQBXYGl4IACi4GLzQFEXFJAEosFxkCUQxff1ZoNAALMggBNw9vZIRoSDT9IxNkdDj4smMglBCMLlV1A2MCgWt9GJx8eL6MrI6QVODQqpkAX1kIZh6+-vSEfmgUJHZoIQQlwKjxwgmqg9wjvFBIGABhTJBuKgAPNFRuGHgKjDnCVXJKTqZUzh4-AEAAkaABZAAyEQklWOzlwiWghl4vFSKC8IGGxS8KAA1ih+CgijBQZDoZI8IjgOk0WtoFcyDcAsjeLtcHgAPQcuBLJgIPTQCxGQwzNAQpCGNAWaB8JAwAkYJB3LIYdwlP4WcnoCwCU7pIYCYWi8WSoA).

---

I know I can solve it by explicitly declaring `el` in `Child`:

```js
class Child extends Parent {
    static elType = window.HTMLElement
    el: HTMLElement
}
```

But I want to avoid that as it's redundant. `el` should always be the instance type of `static elType`.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't using static properties, I'd suggest using [polymorphic `this` types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to represent the constraint that a subclass property will narrow in concert with some other property.  Something like this:

```
class Parent {
    elType = window.Element
    el: InstanceType<this['elType']>
    constructor(input: Element) {
        if (input instanceof this.elType) {
            this.el = input as InstanceType<this['elType']>; // assert
        } else {
            throw new Error()
        }
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    elType = window.HTMLElement
}
let foo = null as unknown as HTMLElement
let ch = new Child(foo)
ch.el.offsetLeft; // okay
```

Here the type of `el` is declared as `InstanceType<this['elType']>`, which will always be related to the specific type of `elType` in each subclass.  That makes assigning something to `this.el` a little tricky, since the compiler can't easily verify that such an assignment is safe for all subclasses.  A type assertion is the most straightforward way around that.

Anyway you can see that this behaves almost exactly as you want, except that the `elType` property is an instance property and not static.

---

If you really want to see this statically, I'd probably end up moving away from straight inheritance and instead I'd use a factory function that creates classes for you.  Like this:

```
const ParentMaker = <T extends Element>(elType: new () => T) => {
    return class Parent {
        static elType = elType;
        el: T;
        constructor(input: Element) {
            let ctor = this.constructor as typeof Parent
            if (input instanceof ctor.elType) {
                this.el = input
            } else {
                throw new Error()
            }
        }
    }
}

const Child = ParentMaker(window.HTMLElement);
let foo = null as unknown as HTMLElement
let ch = new Child(foo)
ch.el.offsetLeft
```

Here `ParentMaker` takes a constructor as an argument and returns a new class whose static and instance side have `elType` and `el` properties strongly typed the way you want.  Of course there's no easy route to inheritance here, but maybe that's all you need: you could always do `class Child extends ParentMaker(window.HTMLElement) { ... }` to make `Child` have its own properties and methods.  You'd only run into trouble if you needed sub-subclasses or for `ch instanceof Parent` to work.

---

Hopefully one of those gives you some ideas for how to proceed.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBJYUAuJiIAoCcB7GAdQEsMALXQgGwE8xD8ZKz4AVNqJAbwFgAUEKSik8WiCg9cIfBGAY+Isaoi0O9GMgC8SAO5lgAE0L6AdAFFaESIpWrR6gFyp0WHBE3aAPFTJQANoA5OreEMEAugB8Do7whO74AK7wGMwAFEYwyRiu1rYKGACUyoKOFUhkAGZIWcA5SkaY2IiEtf5Q5mFaEKUC5ZVDnd20SHrZuUhSbi2e4X7cIT3aUdEA3EgA9FvT0hD4GHFDAL5I6lDIA0PDlET6SMAQD5b4RPgZxceVJ9+iv4N-nEJFIeABhNi0YznAAeGAUxhkciKZSGK10BiMpgsAAkOABZAAyBTsR0BSABqhsSmqhEI40eyVoYxmyWAAGtgGZgHskHiiSSinFqeJKAyng8IWQoRlaYQvuT4JRRuZ2tVLhhCRBqhhNjskIR2SB6EIhAChKBILAEMgAOIKA7sABiCHS+HoqLECXcSFk8kU+JA7IODJ8HFh8JMPEFimiGXRrgldVKOmiSA4KbT10q8gwyXwPJB0l9yMUnpuSBaGHY5w0vQZ6PWf0cLnTTfJQ29mBSaUykzySBjJXLFbEIt7+AZIy7GB7bt5GF67RL-rJo8cNTq-aq7laEGXE9G4X6zfXI3UDP7p5+tcuI-Xqio90ez0Hb0yCofYkpo5-FT-FKmoqiSYEgUpQgyfpFIGwYfIYJhmOY-LEjYpLFO2VIQDSdLikyLI8GynLcryyFDsKWGiuKr7gcYsp0p+XrKuoqrVOqWFajqQEnEAA)